# How to stop in jquery $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to stop  executing javascript code after the line "return false",but it don't.

my english is poor. if anyone understand me,please improve my question thank you!

```
    $('#category-list input').blur(function(){
        var $$ = $(this), $p = $$.prev();
        if ($$.val() != $p.html()) {
            var data = {'key':$$.attr('name'),'value':$$.val()};
            $.post('<?php echo Url::to(['field']); ?>', data).done(function(result){
                if (result != 'ok'){
                    alert(result);
                    return false; /*i need it stop at here!!!!!! but it not*/
                }
            });
            alert(3);
            $p.html($$.val());
        }
        $$.hide();
        $p.show();
    });
```

Comment: Do you want alert(3) to get executed after you get a response from the server? do you want $$.hide() to get executed after you get a response from the server? etc. Please could you let us know what bits of the code should or shouldn't be executed

Comment: `$.post()` acts asynchronously, in its own time, without blocking the surrounding code. The code simply doesn't execute entirely in the order it was written in. The `alert(3);` will always execute before the `.done(function (result) {...})` callback is invoked. A good explanation of this behavior can be found in "[How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)"

Comment: Declaring a function inside another function doesn't have any impact on the outer function at all. Consider: `function outer() { function inner() { return 42; }; return 21; }`. What do you think `outer()` will return?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't stop a parent function inside an ajax completion function because that will most likely fire after the function itself is finished executing. Regardless, its 2 separate events

`$.post` is an asynchronous ajax request. This means, that the `.done()` part of the function will execute AFTER the ajax request comes back.

However, the rest of the function runs synchronously, meaning every (or some) line of code after `.post` will run before the server even responds. To get around this, you need to re-architect how you execute your functions.

let's examine this with a basic function:

```
function getSomeAjax() {
  //1 - the alert will execute first
  alert('first line of execution');
  //2 - the post request will execute second
  $.post('someUrl', data).done(function(result){
     if (result != 'ok'){
       alert('post request complete');
       //this will execute randomly whenever the server responds. 
       //it could be in 1 second, 5 seconds, or 20 seconds
     }
  });
  //3
  alert('last line of execution');
}
```

looking at the example above, you should move any logic that is dependent on the server response into the if clause. Otherwise it will execute regardless of your post request